# Where in Chrome is the "update browser" button?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to update my Chrome version but I can't find the update button in the menus.  Where is it?

Comment: Question shows no research effort. http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95414 is the first result for "update chrome".

Comment: Since when is prior research necessary to ask a question?

Comment: Probably since the beginning. See http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-down ("When should I vote down?"), as well as [this post on meta](http://meta.superuser.com/a/4997/108226) (specifically the part about simple questions). Also try hovering your mouse over the downvote arrow of a question. And finally, don't take downvotes personally.

Comment: I've reopened this question because it definitely does not fall under the *not constructive* criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowhere, really.

If you go to the *About Google Chrome* menu, it'll show you the status of updates. It'll either be checking at the moment …

[image]

… or it could be finished downloading:

[image]

Should an update be available, it will be indicated in the tools/wrench menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can go to "About Google Chrome" in the menu on the right, or just visit the page `chrome://chrome/`.